# SDL2 C++ - Multiple Image Rendering Bug

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks, sdl-2

Before I begin, the IDE I use is Code::Blocks.

I was going to practice the things I learned online about SDL in another project separate from my study project. I wanted to load an image of a ball on top of a background. It worked fine in my study project. I replicated the code on to my test project, and the ball disappeared. Only the background is visible.

I removed the codes that involve the background and it worked fine.

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#undef main

using namespace std;

SDL_Texture *LoadTexture (string filepath, SDL_Renderer *renderTarget){
    SDL_Texture *texture = 0;
    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(filepath.c_str());

    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderTarget, surface);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return texture;
}

int main () {

    SDL_Window *window = 0;
    SDL_Texture *ball = 0;
    SDL_Texture *background_sky = 0;

    SDL_Renderer *renderTarget = 0;

    int frameW, frameH;
    int textureW, textureH;

    //--Crop Instructions--//
    frameW = textureW / 1; //row division
    frameH = textureH / 1; //column division

    SDL_Rect ballcrop;
    ballcrop.x = ballcrop.y = 0;
    ballcrop.w = frameW; //length of selected area
    ballcrop.h = frameH; //height of selected area

    SDL_Rect ballpos;
    ballpos.x = ballpos.y = 10; //ball position
    ballpos.w = ballpos.h = 64; //size of crop
    //---------------------//

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Ball", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderTarget = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);

    ball = LoadTexture("ball.png", renderTarget);
    background_sky = LoadTexture("bg_sky.png", renderTarget);


    SDL_QueryTexture(ball, NULL, NULL, &textureW, &textureH); //crop action

    bool Active = true;
    SDL_Event ev;

    while (Active) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev)!=0) {
            if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                Active = false;

            else if (ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                switch (ev.key.keysym.sym) {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    ballpos.y -= 5;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    ballpos.y += 5;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderClear(renderTarget);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderTarget, background_sky, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderTarget, ball, &ballcrop, &ballpos);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(background_sky);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(ball);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderTarget);

    window = 0;
    ball = background_sky = 0;
    renderTarget = 0;

    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I dont think I want to show the source code of my study project because its **EXTREMELY** messy.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you only comment out the `SDL_RenderCopy` associated with the background, does it still work? Same question for when you reverse the order of `SDL_RenderCopy`s?

Comment: `frameW = textureW / 1;` what is the point of dividing by 1? Also where are you getting the value of textureW... in the posted code it doesn't show it.

Comment: @MicroVirus : yeaaah it does. the background disappears but the ball isnt there. I have to comment out ALL bg-associated code

Comment: @zammalad : its a meticulous thing ^^;

Comment: I think it's best if you step through it with a debugger, line by line, to see what line actually breaks down: is it `SDL_RenderCopy` that fails, or is the ball texture not (properly) loaded to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your calculation of `frameW` and `frameH`; the code that calculates

```
//--Crop Instructions--//
frameW = textureW / 1; //row division
frameH = textureH / 1; //column division
```

Uses `textureW` and `textureH` before these are initialised. Move the entire 'crop instructions' block until after you have called `SDL_QueryTexture`.

Comment: As an aside, I would like to note that you could have easily figured this out yourself, using the debugger. If you don't know how to use one already, now would be a good time to learn the basics. Take the debugger and see if you can find out what went wrong with `frameW` using it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. I did raise this in the comments of the question. The fact that it works if all background drawing stuff is removed suggests he does set it somewhere (but this isn't the full code as he has said).